A set of Constituency Tests
Is there any paper or resource where various constituency tests are listed and analyzed (besides topicalisation, clefting, pseudoclefting and all those tests that are illustrated on English)?
More specifically, I also want to know evidence for IP (TP), CP and tensed VP in terms of constituency tests, and for PP without using the proform.
Any help is very much appreciated.

In what theory/framework of syntax? MP? Something else? Or are you more into dependencies?

@AlexB., I am more into constituency grammars (currently interested in lfg). Does it make a difference though?

The article
Tests for constituents: What they really reveal about the nature of syntactic structure
provides a comprehensive discussion of tests for constituents. I am the author of this article. The article scrutinizes 15 commonly employed tests for constituents that one finds in the syntax literature, documenting their use extensively.
The discussion of the tests is, though, limited to the sentence structures of English. In general, those that employ the tests do so mainly with just English in mind; rarely does one encounter the tests being applied to other languages, and indeed, it is likely that their applicability to other languages is limited. Ideally, each language needs to have its own battery of tests to motivate its syntactic structures.
Concerning the status of IP/TP, it may be difficult to motivate them using tests for constituents, although pro-form substitution seems to work:
(1) John arrived after you arrived.
(2) John arrived after that. (that = you arrived)
Concerning tensed VP, the tests do not for the most part succeed at motivating its existence as a constituent, a fact that is often overlooked by the authors that employ the tests.

You should include a disclaimer that you are the author of this paper.

@Keelan. I have added the disclaimer.

@Keelan Why a disclaimer? He is citing himself as a source. If he is a university professor, why is that not kosher?

@TimOsborne, thanks for the reply! The substitution may say it is a constituent but does not say which one. It might as well be a VP. So basically it depends on assumptions. What is the evidence for CP (where there is no C) or IP in matrix clauses? I am suspecting there is no such evidence. It that is true, claims for CP (which are just assumptions) should be dispensed with.

@TimOsborne, I have a case of ellipsis in Russian. Я пришел домой. - Я тоже [пришел домой]. Tensed verb and everything that follows should be ellided. Another type of ellipsis can retain the auxiliary: Я буду идти домой. - Я тоже буду [идти домой].

I think there is ample evidence that the complements of prepositions are constituents. Since some prepositions also double as subordinators (e.g. before, after, because of), it makes sense to view the complements of subordinators as constituents, too. Note that subordinator = complementizer -- the use of terminology varies depending on the grammarian and the theory of syntax at hand. Therefore I do not think it matters so much what you want to call the constituent (i.e. IP/TP/VP or simply clause), that unit is arguably a constituent.

Your Russian examples involve ellipsis. Many ellipsis mechanisms  clearly do not elide constituents (e.g. gapping, sluicing, pseudogapping, answer ellipsis, etc.), a fact that I have argued extensively elsewhere in my writings. Thus, пришел домой would not be a constituent in the sentence Я тоже пришел домой. Interestingly, though, идти домой in *Я тоже буду идти домой is arguably a constituent; as the complement of буду, the non-finite VP идти домой can and should be viewed as a complete subtree, that is, as a constituent.

@TimOsborne, thanks for the replies! I do not understand how you concluded that the first toze-ellipsis does not have to do with constituents. Just a verb cannot be ellided (*Я тоже [показал] другу книгу, or *Я тоже [показал другу] книгу). But it can be retained (Я тоже пришел), but to my knowledge its interpretation may differ from the example I gave in my previous comment.

I am not sure what you are asking. The ellipsis mechanism at work in your example is similar to what occurs in English (my knowledge of Russian is very basic): John came home. -- Me  too. The ellipsis mechanism in such cases is mysterious, since I am not aware that it has been identified in the literature; at least it does not have a name that I am aware of. In any case, one could perhaps argue that came home is a constituent, but to do so, it would have to be T' constituent due to the presence of too. I think much of phrase syntax would be loathe to do that.

@TimOsborne, could you please explain why it would have to be T'?

The constituent cannot be a TP because it has to exclude the subject. The constituent must also exclude the too/тоже, which again indicates that it cannot be a phrasal XP constituent. I therefore assume that it must be a bar-level constituent, and of T because it includes the finite verb. However, I do not like X-bar syntax, nor do I for a second that the strict binarity of branching assumed in most modern X-bar theoretic accounts is at all plausible. That is just not a good way to model syntactic structures.

@TimOsborne, it does make a lot of sense. I'm reading Tallman's book on the planar-fractal method (he even cited you). Do you know anything about it?

Would you please provide the full citation for that book. I may want to take a look.

@TimOsborne, Tallman, Adam J. R., Auderset, Sandra & Uchihara, Hiroto (eds.). 2024. Constituency and convergence in the Americas. (Topics in Phonological Diversity 1). Berlin: Language Science Press.

Many thanks. I see that the book is very recent.
